# Si el archivo existe descargar en caso de que no, subir, html php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Estoy generando un modulo de archivos que en base a una solicitud con id único debe contar con archivos los cuales están definidos por tipo en una base de datos, la idea es que si el archivo esta poder descargarlo y en caso de no estar subirlo. e realizado varias pruebas e intentos y logro cargar la lista de archivos por tipo y en caso de encontrar conciencia poder realizar la descarga no así en el caso contrario que permita subir el archivo.

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="3">Programa Vigilancia</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Tipo</th>
<th>Fecha</th>
<th>Acciones</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($documentos_tipo as $tipo) : ?>
<?php if($tipo['etapa'] == "Programa Vigilancia"):?>
<tr>
<?php foreach ($documentos as $documento):?>
<?php if($documento->descripcion == $tipo['descripcion']): ?>
<td><?php echo $tipo['descripcion']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($documento->fecha_ingreso)); ?></td>
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url().str_replace(FCPATH,'',$documento->ruta);?>" class="btn btn-primary " target="_blank"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Descargar</a></td>                                                                                                
<?php endif;?>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $tipo['descripcion']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "---"; ?></td>
<td><a href="<?php echo site_url('solicitud_controller/subeArchivo/'.$documento->id_solicitud.'-'.$tipo['id_tipo_documento']);?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Subir Archivo</a></td>
</tr>            
<?php endif; ?>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

En el primer foreach traigo la lista de documentos por tipo, luego consulto si son del mismo etapa (hay varias etapas distintas con sus listados de documentos), luego en el siguiente foreach traigo la lista de documentos de la solicitud y consulto si hay conciencia de descripción si la hay que traiga el nombre del documento la fecha en que se cargo y la opción de descargarlo acá es cuando no se cumple esta coincidencia es que necesito que permita subirlo.

Comment: Saludos. Asumiendo que la URL sí corresponde al archivo (ruta, nombre, etc) al tag **a** agregale **download** como propiedad **<a [lo demás que tangas necesites] download><i [lo que tienes]></i></a>**

Comment: estimado, si esta descargando bien el archivo, mi problema es con armar la tabla. que tenga el botón de descargar cuando sea el caso o de subir archivo para el caso contrario.

Comment: o sea tu problema es que no podes agregar un boton en una tabla?

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Creo (por lo que expresas y tu código) te hace falta encontrar un **flag** en tu consulta u origen de datos o usar algún elemento ya existente por su valor para determinar si el documento existe o no para entonces decidir entre el **td** con botón para descarga o uno para subir. No distingo tengas esa parte.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr exactamente eso es lo que busco.

Comment: Habitualmente se hace como te indica @RobertoLeOr en su último comentario. Cuando generas la tabla desde los datos obtenidos en la consulta SQL, ya deberías saber si el archivo existe o no, sea porque tienes un marcador en la tabla que contiene los nombres de archivo, sea porque haces un `LEFT JOIN` y ese dato es `NULL`, etc, eso depende de tu contexto de consulta. La cuestión es ¿tienes algún modo de saber, en ese momento que el archivo existe? Impleméntalo. ¿No hay modo de saberlo? Pues quizá deberías repensar el modelo de datos para facilitar esa tarea.